# Как растянуть текстуру в ibgdx?

Tags: разработка-игр, libgdx, текстура

Имеется текстура, которая должна быть во весь экран. Она 500x250 пикселей. Помещаю ее вот так:

```
batch.draw(background,0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight);
```

Получается вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что можно использовать, чтобы растянуло ее под экран ?

Answer (score 1):

Напишите так:

```
batch.draw(background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```